# JQuery UI Autocomplete WebService Source returning JSON

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json, webservice-client, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been trying for two months to get this code working, and I am close, but still confused. I want the JQuery UI Autocomplete function to call an web service which returns JSON data and display that data for selection, and on selection put the selected value into a hidden field.

There are several issues:
1) The autocomplete function is not firing
2) The source: "/AutoSuggest.asmx/DOTFind?" line throws an invalid object exception
3) The service requires two parameters: (string prefixText, int count) - count tells it how many records to return.
4) I am not at all certain that this code will accept JSON data that comes back from the service

Here is the code:
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

Untitled Page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($) {
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $('h4').addClass('tmpFrameworkLoaded');
                    $('h4').text('jQuery successfully loaded and running!');
                }
            );
    }

</script>

<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading
    {
        background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<div id="divDOTJQuery" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            function log(message) {
                alert(message);
                $("<div/").text(message).prependTo("#log");
                $("#log").attr("scrollTop", 0);
            }
        });

        $("#dotmatch").autocomplete({
            source: "/AutoSuggest.asmx/DOTFind?",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                log(ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            }
        });
    </script>

    <div class="ui-widget">
        DOT Job Title or #:
        <input type="text" id="dotmatch" />
        <input type="hidden" id="DOTNumber" name="DOTNumber" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top: 2em; font-family: Arial">
        Results:<br />
        <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is the web service:

```
[WebMethod(BufferResponse = true, Description = "Lookup a DOT record using part of DOT Number or DOT Title")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string DOTFind(string prefixText, int count)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        count = 10;
    }
    DOT D = new DOT();

    DataView DV = D.View(prefixText, count);
    List<DOT> items = new List<DOT>();
    foreach (DataRow DR in DV.Table.Rows)
    {
        items.Add(new DOT(SQL.ColumnToString(DR, "DOTNumber").Trim(),SQL.ColumnToString(DR, "JobTitle").Trim()));
    }
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(items.GetType());
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, items);
    string jsonString = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    ms.Close();
    return jsonString;
}
```

I would deeply appreciate any help with this that you can offer.

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

I see you haven't specified that `.autocomplete()` should expect `application/json`data from your web service. Do this by specifying `dataType: "json"` in the call to `.autocomplete()`.

```
$("#dotmatch").autocomplete({
        source: "/AutoSuggest.asmx/DOTFind?",
        minLength: 2,
        dataType: "json" //specify dataType
        select: function(event, ui) {
            log(ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Function is not firing yet, so cannot test.

Comment: @Bob: Have you verified the data returned by your web service by other means? i.e. by manually invoking `/AutoSuggest.asmx/DOTFind?` or something like that?

Comment: Yes - I have checked out the webservice and it works fine. The issue right now is that my autocomplete function is not firing.

Comment: @Bob: Which version of jQuery are you using? Try placing `.autocomplete()` inside the `ready()`. Is `#dotmatch` a textbox or the containing div? Please post the relevant HTML markup too.

Answer (score 0):

autocomplete uses JSONP, NOT JSON,

so add parameter callback=?, or anything you like

```
$("#dotmatch").autocomplete({
    source: "/AutoSuggest.asmx/DOTFind?callback=?",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        log(ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    }
});
```

In a webservice try wrap JSON into callback_value(YOUR_JSON);

But I'am not sure about get parameters in WebMethods, so you can use Generic Handler (ashx) instead.

Comment: Actually, autocomplete can use either JSON or JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

The "code not firing" problem turned out to be easily detectible when I used FireFox and FireBug. I could see that the event firing line was having a problem launching the request. When I tuned that line, it started firing OK. Then I encountered a series of problems like "can't use GET - must use POST" and "Data returned begins with a 'D '". I worked through each of them and the code now works. When I get it all cleaned up, I am going to write it up and post the result somewhere. Maybe here.